# I have a slidingTabLayout and I keep getting this RunTime exception?

Tags: java, android, exception, runtime

I have set up a sliding tab layout and I keep getting this runtime exception when switching between tabs. I am not sure exactly what this means, can anyone shed some light on the situation?

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: com.athena.athena.MainActivitys.MainActivity@42988d90 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
                                                                   at com.athena.athena.MainActivitys.Tags.onAttach(Tags.java:84)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1019)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:552)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:514)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:495)
                                                                   at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener.onTabSelected(TabLayout.java:1778)
                                                                   at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:871)
                                                                   at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:841)
                                                                   at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab.select(TabLayout.java:1115)
                                                                   at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$1.onClick(TabLayout.java:665)
                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)



 public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        //2 steps creating a fragment, create the fragment class and create the UI for it
        Fragment fragment = null;
        //we dont want it to return our place holder Fragment instead we want to switch bewtween 3
        //create a switch case based on the position applied or the fragment selected
        switch (position) {
            case HOME:
                fragment = Dashboard.newInstance("","");
                break;
            case TAGS:
                fragment = Tags.newInstance("","");
                break;
            case MY_RECENT:
                fragment = Recent.newInstance("","");
                break;
            case MY_POINTS:
                fragment = Points.newInstance("", "");
                break;
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Home";
            case 1:
                return "Points";
            case 2:
                return "Recent";
            case 3:
                return "Tags";
        }
        return null;
    }
}

}
```

I Updated the question to make it more informative.

Comment: You need to post your code as well.

Answer (score 0):

As your exception says :
 java.lang.RuntimeException: com.athena.athena.MainActivitys.MainActivity@42988d90 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener

Can you please check whether MainActivity is implementing OnFragmentInteractionListener class ?

Comment: Also the problem is that when i click on myRecent it takes me to the Tags page, and tells me to implement my listener

Comment: Why should my Tag activity affect myRecent Activity?

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28822229/error-must-implement-onfragmentinteractionlistener