# I got fragment error too much every time I get in imports or these error

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button1;
        Button button2;
        button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment=null;
                fragment =new FragmentOne();
                FragmentManager fm=  getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft= fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.mainFragment,fragment);
                ft.commit();



            }
        });
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });





//        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
//        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

//        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
//        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View view) {
//                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
//                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
//            }
//        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

i have these things in next class
.... i have only background color in both fragments which extends fragment. Any help will be greately appriciated.

My xml fine which got error is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.shailendra.colorfragment.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Frag 1"
        android:id="@+id/button1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Frag 2"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <fragment
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:name="com.example.shailendra.colorfragment.FragmentOne"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_fragment_one">

     </fragment>


</LinearLayout>
```

My log cat file says:

> ```
>  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #29
>  : Must specify unique android:id, android:tag, or have a parent with an id for com.example.shailendra.colorfragment.FragmentOne       
>  at
> android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2260)
>  at
> android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
>  at
> android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is an interaction listener in your fragments. While you use fragmentinteractionlistener , you must implement it... otherwise you can remove it

This is fine just remove interaction. Hope you reach to answer.

Comment: oh you are awesome but can you please tell me why has this to bedone

Comment: So you may have directly chosen fragment from layout file. The thing is there is interactionlistener used default when you create it, which should have further be reused... as you have to define button you put it. So best solution is dont use it.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
android:name="com.example.shailendra.colorfragment.FragmentOne"
```

to

```
class="com.example.shailendra.colorfragment.FragmentOne"
```

Comment: done but got this    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.example.shailendra.colorfragment.MainActivity@52815594 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener

Comment: @rishav it is a different question, not relevant to this post. this problem is about how to implement interface. I suggest you need to learn Java before go to Android

Answer (score 0):

In your case fragment loaded by xml dont need to replace again, If you are replacing fragment by using code than in **xml** use **Framelyout**

```
<FrameLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:id="@+id/mainFragment"/>
```

If you want to replace fragment by code then You should add **FrameLayout** in xml and remove **fragment** tag

Comment: got this      Process: com.example.shailendra.colorfragment, PID: 1560
                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: com.example.shailendra.colorfragment.MainActivity@528168d8 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener

Comment: If you try to achieve this type functionality then check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28822229/error-must-implement-onfragmentinteractionlistener

Comment: You should implement interface in you Activity which are using in Fragment

Answer (score 0):

```
<fragment
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:name="com.example.shailendra.colorfragment.FragmentOne"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_fragment_one">

     </fragment>
```

This "fragment" tag

```
   //Dynamically render the fragment layout
android:name="com.example.shailendra.colorfragment.FragmentOne" 
    //statically render the layout
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_fragment_one"
```

these two lines doing same task, rendering the layout. you remove "tools: layout" line.  **But anyhow that is not creating the exception.**

Comment: Just now I tested your code, your layout file not creating any exception. so please provide your fragment file also.