# Navigation Drawer: fragmentTransaction.commit() is crashing my application

Tags: android, navigation, commit, drawer, fragmenttransaction

I'm creating Navigation Drawer, it works until i started to add fragments, it is crashing after `fragmentTransaction.commit();`. But i am unable to understand why this happens. Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
   import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
   import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
   import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
   import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
   import android.util.Log;

  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  Toolbar toolbar;
  DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
  ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
  FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawerLayout= (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        actionBarDrawerToggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close);

        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);


        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_container, new HomeFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home . . .");


    }
```

Here is the log:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.example.hakobm.navdrawer, PID: 351
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hakobm.navdrawer/com.example.hakobm.navdrawer.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.example.hakobm.navdrawer.MainActivity@f0b255b must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.example.hakobm.navdrawer.MainActivity@f0b255b must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
                                                                              at com.example.hakobm.navdrawer.HomeFragment.onAttach(HomeFragment.java:75)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1231)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut(FragmentTransition.java:1085)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.calculateFragments(FragmentTransition.java:976)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:95)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2146)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:607)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6268)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Post error log here.

Comment: Just make sure you are using same import in both classes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28822229/error-must-implement-onfragmentinteractionlistener

Comment: I've found the issue , something wrong with my fragment Activity, i just create en empty activity and extend Fragment, now it works thanks to ALL

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for calling your fragment...

```
  FragmentTransaction fragmenttransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  HomeFragment regcomplainfragment = new HomeFragment();
  fragmenttransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, regcomplainfragment).addToBackStack("tag");
  fragmenttransaction.commit();
```

and remove below line;

```
  getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home . . .");
```

Comment: again crush, i've added the log

Answer (score 0):

I think this is useful for you

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context = getApplicationContext();

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_listview);



    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        FragmentTransaction tx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        tx.replace(R.id.main_container,new HomeFragment());
        tx.commit();
    }

    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();


    title = new String[]{ Here you use menu title
    };

    icon = new int[]{ here show menu icon};

    mMenuAdapter = new HomeMenuListAdapter(context, title, icon);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(mMenuAdapter);
    mMenuAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {



            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            switch (position) {

                case 0:

            }
            ft.commit();
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawer);

        }
    });


      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your MainActivity should be implement interface OnFragmentInteractionListener