# Calling a fragment from onOptionsItemSelected() method of MainActivity

Tags: android, tabs, optionmenu

In my MainActivity, this is my option menu code --

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_profile) {
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.action_password) {
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.action_update) {
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.action_signin) {
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.action_help) {
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.action_use_terms) {
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.action_policy) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Created a fragment named fragment_changepassword.xml and ChangePassword.java.
Now i want to call that fragment from --

```
if (id == R.id.action_password) {
            return true;
        }
```

this part, but searched google but not getting any help, finally came here with a hope.

Calling other fragments from the Tab is easier like this --

```
@Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 1) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
                return rootView;
            } else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 2) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_videos, container, false);
                return rootView;
            } else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 3){
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messages, container, false);
                return rootView;
            }
            else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 4){
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_audios, container, false);
                return rootView;
            }
            else {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_images, container, false);
                return rootView;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To set fragment in a container(defined in xml) from an activity, you have to use SupportFragmentManager.
Try this code

```
if (id == R.id.action_password) {
      getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
              .replace(R.id.container, ChangePasswordFragment.newInstance())
              .commit();
      return true;
    }
```

Provide a `newInstance()` method inside your fragment calss. Something like this -

```
public static ChangePasswordFragment newInstance() {
    return new ChangePasswordFragment();
  }
```

Comment: @Nayan Attach logcat message in comments or in your question, not in my answer.

Comment: You must have some interface inside your fragment which needs to be implemented in your activity. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28822229/error-must-implement-onfragmentinteractionlistener).